# mongodb equivalent sql inner join

Tags: mysql, mongodb, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

- endpoint
- stream
- configuration

This is the structure of **endpoint table**

```
------------------
| GUID | ENABLED |
------------------
| aaa  | false   |
------------------
| bbb  | true    |
------------------
```

This is the structure of **stream table**

```
------------------
| GUID | VALUE   |
------------------
| aaa  | aaa1    |
------------------
| bbb  | bbb1    |
------------------
```

And this is the structure of **configuration table**

```
--------------------------
| GUID | JSON            |
--------------------------
| aaa  | {"guid": "aaa"} |
--------------------------
| bbb  | {"guid": "aaa"} |
--------------------------
```

I need to have the stream records where endpoint is enabled,  **inner join** between tables like this

```
select stream.*,configuration.*,endpoint.* from configuration, stream
inner join endpoint on stream.guid=endpoint.guid where
stream.guid=configuration.guid and endpoint.enabled='true'
```

How can I do this in MongoDB?
Thanks

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Hello Smita, I know $lookup and I use it, but I don't know the correct syntax to do my filter query

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: {
            $lookup: {
                from: "configuration",
                localField: "guid",
                foreignField: "guid",
                as: "config"
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "endpoint",
                localField: "guid",
                foreignField: "guid",
                as: "endpoint"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "endpoint.enabled": "true"
            }
        }

Comment: and whats the problem then?

Comment: @MauroSala , forget sql, think in mongodb. It has a special design called embedding to achieve special advantages like high performance.

Comment: @SmitaAhinave with this code the result array is empty

Comment: @LakmalVithanage ok, I don't want to use SQL, but how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Frankly, if this is your table structure and your mindset is SQL, forget mongo and use a relational database instead. If that does not suit your needs, read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/ and rethink your application design. What you ask is possible (and others attempt to explain how), but it does not make any sense in the context of a document based db.